# Detect objects in an image opencv

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

[image: Image in which object needs to be detected]

I have attached an image which consists of objects. The problem is to find the count of the objects present in the image. I have tried opencv template matching but it is not invariant to scale, rotation and deformation means if I take a patch of object from this image and try to do template matching then there will some of the object which will not match juts because they are little bit deformed or differently oriented. The problem with template matching is first I have to take the template from the query image itself. So if the image is at different there will not be matches.

Is there any better way to tackle this kind of problem.

P.S. The objects need not to be same every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's pretty simple if you make use of the shiny rod edges. No need for template matching. Look at the below output image

[image]

What i did:

1. Threshold and dilate the image
2. Count contours in the region within approximately the area of the circles.

There are many methods you can use. Direct hough circles might work if you pass the parameters properly. But this is the safest i think.
That's a good estimate for your count, can get better if i threshold properly( 3 rods weren't accounted for in this). By saying the objects might not be the same always if you mean completely different objects, then you need to do what requires with that image

Comment: I don't know what language he is using. Moreover the explanation would do i guess.

Comment: the task looks simple but needs some tricky ways to  get %100 correct answer

Comment: Ya, that's true. But my threshold values are also not so accurate..i randomly put the values. Same for the no.of dilations. If i correct those i may get better answer

Comment: Actually there are 4 unaccounted for, two at the bottom left, one bottom right, and one on the left 7 pegs up.

Comment: since the objects need not be same every time, so using thresholding won't work for the cases in which object itself is having low gray level values. What function have you used for finding the contours?                                         P.S : I am using Opencv and python. and  I tried doing this using opencv function template matching.

Comment: Template matching is not something suggested to be used for this kind of problem. If your image is typically of this type, then this method would work even if the gray level values deviate a little. If there's another image you'd like to try on, put that. By saying objects need not be same everytime if its something different like apples for example to count, then that's different. Until its this type of rods with similar image settings, it works with decent estimate

Comment: "Count contours in the region within approximately the area of the circles." How to do this?

Comment: Find Contours. **(im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)**
Find area of contoours with **(area = cv2.contourArea(cnt))**. Put limits like 20<area<200 something like that.