# Detecting objects in an image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

[image]

I have attached an image which consists of objects. The problem is to find the count of the objects present in the image. I have tried opencv find contour function and template matching but it doesn't work well. The objects present in the image need not be same.

Is there any better way to tackle this kind of problem.

```
im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(bilateral_filtered_image,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
new_cnts=[]
for c in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    k = cv2.isContourConvex(c)
    if (20<area<200):
        new_cnts.append(c)
```

Comment: What's the difference with [your other question?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45898282/5008845)

Comment: Agree with @Miki , just invert your image.

Comment: I tried doing the same thing suggested but didn't get satisfying results. What I am asking is there can be general way which can be used to detect objects irrespective of their appearance. Just because the object is not same as object in the previous question, introduce the inversion operation.

Answer (score 0):

1: Threshold into blob find (with some refinement in blob size and shape to be more specific).

or 2: Canny edge filter into circle find.  They all seem pretty circular and more or less have clean edges.

That being said, I am only basing off your given image, the first step in imaging is always stacking the deck with lighting and camera angle when you can.  There are quite a few ways you could add some light to this setup to make the vision setup way more robust no matter which modality you chose.

Comment: The thing is I can optimise to detect the object accurately for this image but it should work in general. Like there can be different objects a different scale, may be affine transformed, illuminated differently. I want to account for those situations also. Atleast the approach should be such that it can work with quite good accuracy for different kind of objects

Comment: @KaranKumar There's no such thing as an accurate general object detection. I worked with logo detection and tracking for almost a year and I used everything from SURF, SIFT, ORB to template matching and bundle min-hashing. Every time I had to fine tune my code for the specific type of logos that I was trying to detect.

Comment: So the kinda catch 22 in what you are suggesting in smart find tools or things that use NN type setups, you have to have tons of training data with organized and well cropped samples as well as excellent representation of sample distribution, which often takes more time than setting up the particular solution with standard vision tools.